# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model when I implemented perceptual loss for GAN

Tags: python, keras

I have implemented a perceptual loss in pix2pix model for image to image translation, here is my link https://github.com/yug125lk/GAN/blob/main/git.ipynb but I have got this error:

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model: expected shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), found shape=(1, 16, 16, 1) .

I tried to upsamling layers by Conv2DTranspose in discriminator to get the same shape (256, 256) but still not working. can someone help me please, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you fix the channel number as well (from 1 to 3) ?

Comment: Yes, and the code worked without the perceptual loss function, when I run with it , I got this error.